# There is an extremely high amount of CPU usage in this simple game

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crash

I have a game where debris spawns and the player has to dodge it, and the debris is spawned with a function that calls the `addAlien` function in it. This function is called         `updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate()`. The problem is it is using like 80% of CPU and I have no idea why... When I remove it the app works perfectly, but with it it crashes. Could someone tell me what I should do to fix this? All help is greatly appreciated: Code posted below

```
         func updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(timeSinceLastUpdate: CFTimeInterval){
                          lastYieldTimeInterval += timeSinceLastUpdate
                    if(lastYieldTimeInterval > 1){
                   lastYieldTimeInterval = 0
                   addAlien()
                          }
                   }
//**Where this function is called:** (last line of this function)

  override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        scoreLabel.text =  scoreVarInLabel + String(accessVar.gameScore)

        if(pixelman.position.x<20){
            pixelman.position.x = 20
        }
        if(pixelman.position.x>self.frame.width-5){
            pixelman.position.x = self.frame.width-5
        }
        var timeSinceLastUpdate = currentTime - lastUpdateTimerInterval
        lastUpdateTimerInterval = currentTime

        if(timeSinceLastUpdate > 1){
            timeSinceLastUpdate = 1/60
            lastUpdateTimerInterval = currentTime
        }
        // The below line is what is causing 80% CPU Usage

        updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(timeSinceLastUpdate)

    }
```

Thank you SO much in advance

As a side note, I apologize for the specificity of the question: I want to understand in general what is causing this crash.

Comment: Please use Instruments to find the answer to your problem. You access it via the `Product -> Profile` menu item in Xcode, then select `Time Profiler` and hit the red Record button. That will tell you exactly what percentage of CPU time is spent on every line of code in your app. If you can't figure out how to fix the problem after looking at that data, please edit this question including the data from Instruments and we can help you out with a solution.

Comment: Hi Abhi! I have used Time Profiler and it is saying that the problem lies in that function. This is how I was able to narrow down the error function and what is causing the high CPU usage. Unfortunately I do not have the necessary amount of reputation to post images

Comment: You can post an image to some other site, like imageur, and link to it. Which line of code in the function specifically is using all the CPU usage?